# Does Mongrel do IPv6 well?

Tags: apache-2.2, ipv6, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

I'm using 
mongrel + apache 2.2 + mod_proxy_balancer.

apache2.2 is IPv6 well
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/bind.html#ipv6

Does Mongrel do IPv6 well?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache in front of mongrel,  the connection between them is local to the host. Therefore, the mongrel doesn't really care what protocol is used to communicate with the client, so it's a non-issue.

That said, I don't know whether or not mongrel does speak ipv6, but I imagine it probably does, out of the box.